# Re-Initialize jQuery after XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, xmlhttprequest

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap's Popover feature on a sidebar. The sidebar is fetched and reloads the content every 30 seconds. I'm suing XMLHttpRequest to reload the content of the sidebar by fetching a file called stats.php.

The following code is the "refresh" code which resides in the header of the page.

```
function onIndexLoad()
{
    setInterval(onTimerCallback, 30000);
}

function onTimerCallback()
{
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
      if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
      {
          document.getElementById("stats").style.opacity = 0;
          setTimeout(function() {
              document.getElementById("stats").innerHTML = request.responseText;
                document.getElementById("stats").style.opacity = 100;
              }, 1000);
      }
  }
  request.open("GET", "stats.php", true);
  request.send();
}
```

The above code works flawlessly, however, after it reloads the #stats div, the popover no long does what it's supposed to - popup.

The popover code is in the stats.php in a foreach() loop because I have multiple popover scripts I need because there are multiple popovers on the sidebar.

Here's my popover code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[rel=popover_$id]').popover({
        placement:'right',
        title:'$title',
        content: $('#popover_content_$id').html()
  });
});
```

The `$id` and `$title` are dynamic as they are pulled from the foreach() loop.

How can I fix it so after the div reloads, the popover function will reinitialize?

---

```
$("a[rel=popover_controller_$cid]").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('a[rel=popover_$id]').popover({
                placement:'right',
                title:'$title',
                content: $('#popover_content_$id').html()
        });
    }
});
```

I have also tried:

```
$("a[rel=popover_controller_$cid]").on("mouseover", function () {
    $('a[rel=popover_$id]').popover({
            placement:'right',
            title:'$title',
            content: $('#popover_content_$id').html()
    });
});
```

Comment: Search up jquery for .on() and .live(). It is what you are looking for.

Comment: I've updated my original post with the new code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The on function will only work on an object that is defined at initialization. Use $(document).on("click","a[rel=popover_controller_$cid]", function(){...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.live` is depreciated. use `.on` delegation

try something like this:

```
$('#stats').on("mouseenter", "a[rel=popover_controller_$cid]",function () {
        $('a[rel=popover_$id]').popover({
                placement:'right',
                title:'$title',
                content: $('#popover_content_$id').html()
        });

});
```

This delegates the mouseenter event from `#stats` to `a[rel=popover_controller_$cid]` and because the event is delegated it will still fire when `#stats` contents are replaced.

be careful - you will keep initializing popover on each mouseover. that might be bad.

while you are at it - you should use jquery's ajax instead of native xhr. its easier and more cross browser.

```
$.get('stats.php', function(d){
    $('#stats').html(d);
};
```

--

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get('stats.php', function(data) {
        $('#stats').html(data);
    });
}, 30000);
```

Comment: I added an interval (to your post)...is there a way to only refresh a specific div rather than the whole page. The current interval code, when it refreshes, it almost "freezes" up the whole page until it's loaded.

Comment: only the #stats is replaced every 30 seconds. is that a large part of the page? you can replace any div just like you replace #stats. put an id on that div and replace that id. ex: `<div id='test'></div> $("#test").html(d);`

Comment: I got it figured out. I had a typo. Your code works flawlessly. Thanks again!

Comment: there is one thing that bugs me about this, though. After the #stats is reloaded, I have to hover over the link to activate the popover twice to activate it. If I hover over it once, it doesn't popup.

Comment: yeah because once you mouseenter you init the widget, but the widget doesnt fire because it shows on mouseenter (which already happened). the way to fix it would be to manually make it show itself. look at the api and see if it lets you do that. only do this once when you init it (with flag ?)